# creation of filesystem image in another image

Tags: filesystem

I am creating Ubuntu raspberry pi os from scratch using this

https://a-delacruz.github.io/ubuntu/rpi3-setup-filesystem

Iam struck here

[image]

please provide full procedure 
1. full filesystem creation as mention in the picture
2. full commands for mounting and populating the RPI images etc

Thanking you in Advance

Comment: `please provide full procedure` yeah nah that's not how it works - if you don't know how to use fdisk, and the friendly fdisk manual doesn't help, perhaps you should consider something else

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. And please don't use pictures, instead paste output of commands as text into the question.